# How do you break at first line of code that executes after interaction with a user interface. Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am developing an application that uses a third party vendor component as part of the UI. I need to see the very next line of code that executes following clicking on a certain area of the control. I don't know where to set a break point because I don't know where execution is directed. This control contains tens of thousands of lines of code, so static analysis is not a workable option.

VB6 used to have a way you could step through the code up until just before and just after clicking/doing something on the UI, but I haven't been able to find it in VS 2010. Does anyone know what the trick is for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find code that executes following clicking on a control with the [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool (developed by me, 30-day trial). Then you can set a breakpoint on this line of code.